# Timeout occurs when trying to remote access from a windows laptop to a linux board via 4g network over no-ip

Tags: linux, remote-access, noip

I need to have remote access from a windows pc to a board that is connected to a modem an has access to 4G network. The board runs debian jessie 8.1 armbian. I have also created a dedicated host name in https://my.noip.com. Further more according to this helpful guide https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/09/02/configuring-ddclient-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-at-noip-com/ I configured ddclient to update my dynamic DNS at noip.com. The configuration file consists of:

```
protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com/, web-skip='IP Address'
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com
login=user
password=pwd
myhostname
```

When I try to connect with winscp via either sftp or ftp I get a timeout.

Also when I try to ping myhostname it resolves the ip correctly but it does not receive any packet at all. What I am doing wrong?

Since the access is over 4g I don't know what router I'm behind of in order to port forward accordingly if that is the case.

Comment: Normally you can't, the phone network blocks incoming connections to its customers (otherwise think of the security issues). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932962/how-to-bypass-blocking-of-all-incoming-connections-on-3g-4g-network) for a possible workaround. Another possibility would be to have the mobile system set up a VPN through which you can connect to it.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks a lot of your answers. Regarding vpn and since I'm quite new with the vpn concept where one can begin for setting it on a linux machine. Is there any preferable software ?

Comment: Openconnect or pptp should do it. You need clients on both your PC and the 4G-connected thing, and a server on some 3rd machine (to which both your PC or the device connect via VPN). This third machine is either a hosted server, or a some machine on the same network as your PC (with port forwarding from the router). A RPi could be a good candidate for a home setup. No direct experience with this, though.